# Debugging C++ variables in Android Studio

Tags: c++, arrays, android-studio, debugging, watch

I have an Android app that involves both Java and C++ code. I'm currently debugging it from Android Studio on Device. I have a function parameter of `const char*` type. Whenever I try to view the value of the variable, it shows me the first value in the string.

Is it possible to view the entire null-terminated string, or is there a way to view a range of variables in an array, similar to Visual Studio's *array_name,array_size*-format?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best I could find is printing variables with lldb.

1. Open lldb window while in debug
2. write `p/s [variable_name]`, and it should print out the contents of the string.

If someone knows a better way, please let me know.